# Where should i be using removeFromSuperview in relation to adding views to a table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a little table that works pretty well. But I was told to remove my subviews at some stage incase the call to drawn the table happens again for whatever reason. I was told it can be handled using removeFromSuperview.

Where and how should i handle this? I need to use tags to identify the cells or views?

Here is my code to create my views.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0]];

if (indexPath.row == 0) 
{
    [cell setText:@"Show only Airports"];
    showAirportsOnlySegment = [ [ UISegmentedControl alloc ] initWithFrame: 
CGRectMake(100, 4, 80, 28) ];
    [ showAirportsOnlySegment insertSegmentWithTitle: @"Yes" atIndex: 0 
animated: NO ];
    [ showAirportsOnlySegment insertSegmentWithTitle: @"No" atIndex: 1 animated: 
NO ];
    showAirportsOnlySegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    showAirportsOnlySegment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    showAirportsOnlySegment.tag = 1;
    showAirportsOnlySegment.enabled = YES;
    [showAirportsOnlySegment addTarget:self action:@selector(airConOnOffAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [ cell addSubview: showAirportsOnlySegment ];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:showAirportsOnlySegment];        
    [showAirportsOnlySegment release];
} 
else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
{
    [cell setText:@"Air Con?"];     
    airConSegment = [ [ UISegmentedControl alloc ] initWithFrame: 
CGRectMake(100, 4, 80, 28) ];
    [ airConSegment insertSegmentWithTitle: @"Yes" atIndex: 0 animated: NO ];
    [ airConSegment insertSegmentWithTitle: @"No" atIndex: 1 animated: NO ];
    airConSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    airConSegment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    airConSegment.tag = 2;
    [airConSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(airConOnOffAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    airConSegment.enabled = YES;
    [ cell addSubview: airConSegment ];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:airConSegment];
    [airConSegment release];
}   
return cell;
}
```

Can anybody advise how to handle the remove the subviews?

Many THanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to customize your first and second row. However, the cell might got reused because you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, so your custom subviews might reappear again in other row if you don't clean up your cell properly after dequeuing. In this case I would suggest that you keep your subviews in instance variables, says `view1` and `view2`, and after dequeuing you just do:

```
if (view1.superview == cell) {
    [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    [view1 release];
}
else if (view2.superview == cell) {
    [view2 removeFromSuperview];
    [view2 release];
}
```

then your subview will not appear in the reused cell.

Comment: I insert those lines of code into my method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath  after the code that gets the cell? And that will check if it needs to release the view? Thanks -Code

Comment: I was pretty sure that we do not need to release the views since as you can see they are released in the code above [airConSegment release]; or have i misunderstood this?

Comment: I guess you are right. You also have to fix few points in your code so just ignore my retain/release if it does not sound right. The point here is how to remove it from the reused cell. However, I myself would keep everything retained and release it explicitly when I need to so I can sure it would not be dealloc accidentally e.g. removeFromSuperview but still need to use it later.